# Laravel Form select disable first option

Tags: forms, laravel, select

I have this code on my view

`{!! Form::select('room', $rooms, Input::old('room'), array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}`

and this on my controller

`$rooms = array('' => 'Select Room') + $rooms;`

I wanted the first option to be selected and disabled which is the "Select Room". I tried to put it also in array and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable only one option from select list then you can do this in html like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This will disable first option disabled.

For reff. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

Comment: yeah i know that. but im using the laravel `Form::select()`  and the contents of the select options are dynamic

Comment: In larvavel, there is have not any way to show some options disabled, So you should use php for loop for achieving this approch.